# Scala Annotation List?

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-2.8

I wanted to ask if there is a list of annotations for Scala 2.8.0?
I stumbled upon @inline and @specialized but it would be nice if there is a complete list which also explains what they do exactly.

If such a list doesn't exist: Are there some annotations one should be familiar with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tour of Scala Annotations:
http://www.scala-lang.org/node/106

Internals of Scala Annotations:
http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/5

The tour is out of date now. There are several more annotations built into Scala now.

The **Known Subclasses** section of the Scaladoc for **scala.annotation.Annotation** provides a fairly significant list (below is as of 2.12.1):

> SerialVersionUID, ClassfileAnnotation, StaticAnnotation, TypeConstraint, compileTimeOnly, elidable, implicitAmbiguous, implicitNotFound, beanGetter, beanSetter, companionClass, companionMethod, companionObject, field, getter, languageFeature, param, setter, strictfp, switch, tailrec, uncheckedStable, uncheckedVariance, unspecialized, varargs, BeanDescription, BeanDisplayName, BeanInfoSkip, BeanProperty, BooleanBeanProperty, deprecated, deprecatedInheritance, deprecatedName, deprecatedOverriding, inline, native, noinline, specialized, throws, transient, unchecked, volatile, BeanInfo, remote

SOURCE: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/Annotation.html

Comment: @JosephLust you are correct. I have made note of the shortcomings of the tour and added a reference to the Scaladoc with an excerpt.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to get a list of all Scala annotations. Just go to http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/Annotation.html and click on "Known subclasses". Today, I get

BeanDescription, BeanDisplayName, BeanInfo, BeanInfoSkip, BeanProperty, BooleanBeanProperty, ClassfileAnnotation, SerialVersionUID, StaticAnnotation, TypeConstraint, beanGetter, beanSetter, cloneable, cpsParam, deprecated, deprecatedName, elidable, field, getter, implicitNotFound, inline, native, noinline, param, remote, serializable, setter, specialized, strictfp, switch, tailrec, throws, transient, unchecked, uncheckedStable, uncheckedVariance, varargs, volatile

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

The official ["The Scala Language Specification Version 2.8"](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) actually also has a nice list of annotations in it with some explanation. (Chapter 11, page 133ff.)

Although for example @inline isn't listed there. So it seems not to be complete either.

Answer (score 1):

See [exhaustive annotation list](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/index.html) for Scala `2.12+`. Head link, will stay up to date.